# What would happen if I covered my deck in pavers?

Tags: deck, pavers

I have a deck. A very strong deck. Instead of sealing it every year, could I cover it in pavers instead?

The wood is treated, and the deck is raised so it would drain. Also, the pavers would protect it from the sun.

What could go wrong?

Comment: Well, you have to ask yourself: why doesn't everybody do it this way?

Comment: Exactly, why don't they? Cost of the pavers? Having to reinforce the deck?

Comment: The pavers may trap water and start a dry rot problem. I have seen this problem with outdoor carpeting. Never heard of pavers being used.

Comment: Before proceeding you should consult a structural engineer.  You say you have a "very strong deck", but that is opinion based.  Pavers may not weigh "a lot" individually however covering say 18x18 they add significant weight.... Then you have to add the max human load plus furniture etc.  you very well might run out of "very strong" and kill a person or 3 in the collapse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could go wrong?

The concrete pavers are slightly porous and will wick water every time it rains. This will keep water against the wood deck boards for much longer than normal and will shorten the life of the wood. So, less sealing but shorter deck life.

I would find a good oil based sealer like tung or timber oil that will last for more than one season. (I used to use Thompson's but it doesn't last for more than one year.)

Good luck!